# Name of the HP Female Adapter Socket In My Laptop

Tags: power-supply, adapter, socket

I have this HP powerbrick with a 90W capacity (19v 4.7A) that I want to use in my project. I am planning to use it as a power source for my 50W LED. But I want to keep the male socket it has rather than chop it off.

What I need is to know what specific socket name should I search in EBay to use it? Or can anyone recommend me a link and I can search it from there.

I search for HP Power socket and I get this result:
http://www.ebay.ph/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_sacat=0&_nkw=HP+power+socket&LH_PrefLoc=2&_arm=1&_armm=63&_ruu=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ebay.ph%2Fsch%2Fi.html%3F_from%3DR40%26_sacat%3D0%26_nkw%3DHP%2Bpower%2Bsocket%26_arr%3D1

I'm not sure if this is what I am looking for.

Picture of the HP Power Brick
[image: The Power Brick]
Socket
[image: Socket]

Comment: I think it is called: "HP proprietary". On the other hand, most generic 3rd party laptop power supplies come with a bunch of different connectors, you'll have to check the manual for you model or gamble on the pictures.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [3 Contact Laptop Power Supply](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/16047/3-contact-laptop-power-supply)

Answer (score 1):

This is fairly standard connector, and can be found in abundance on Farnell

(http://uk.farnell.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/Search?catalogId=15001&langId=44&storeId=10151&categoryId=700000004991&st=DC%20connector&pageSize=25&showResults=true&pf=110056900)

You just need to measure the outer diameter of the barrel and choose the one that suits from the above link.

I have narrowed the search by gender, but just check it is a female one you're buying!

Enjoy.