# Offical Name of Dell/HP Common Laptop Power Jack/Plug

Tags: connector, plug, laptop

I have seen this question asked before, but never has it gotten a real answer. With the popularity of this plug I find it hard to believe it does not have a standard name or IEC name.

Does anyone know the real name of this or is it truly just an oddball DC Barrel-jack connector that HP and Dell love to use?

[image]
Here is a related question with no good answer:
[Question 1](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/169110/name-of-the-hp-female-adapter-socket-in-my-laptop)
And another here:[Question2](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/16047/3-contact-laptop-power-supply)

Just to clarify I really care about the female jack, not the plug.

Comment: "Proprietary 2010 Laptop Series"

Comment: Who says these connectors have a common name ? Go here: http://www.dcpowerjacks.net/catalog/index.php  and see if the one you want is there. On that site search for "Latitude" (Dell series which uses these power jacks) or your favourite model.

Comment: @FakeMoustache Thanks, that is helpful. I was hoping to find these on a commercial website like Digikey or Newark, but this works.

Comment: I have also seen such connectors on ebay, there they're listed on the model laptop in which the are used, just search for your laptop model and "DC jack". It can be that these ebay items are surplus repair stock which is impossible to find on digikey etc.

Comment: So, I'm not looking to replace a laptop one, with the plethora of these and how cheep the adapters are, I wanted to power something off of them. There would be a few dozen students doing this and maybe more assuming it works well, so I was trying to find legit vendors with part numbers so the foot print won't suddenly change, but it seems that is not going to happen.

Comment: Don't open duplicate questions.

Comment: I disagree that it is a duplicate... This made it 4 months with everyone agreeing... I was looking for a name or vendor... Not the communication protocol.